# Strange characters in command prompt

Tags: command-line

I see the kernel command prompt. After few minutes I get a strange character appearing continuously in the commandline preventing me from typing the command. Does anybody know what could be the problem and how to avoid it

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or a photo of the character.

Comment: Does it look at all like this problem from server fault [Ubuntu server 11 showing weird characters on console](https://serverfault.com/questions/286060/ubuntu-server-11-showing-weird-characters-on-console)

Comment: Sorry for coming back late.Using trial and error method what I observed is that after logging into Windows work with Windows applications for some time and then log into Ubuntu. Now I  do not see any strange characters in the command prompt inside Ubuntu. Looks weird but this is what I observed.

Comment: did you mean to link an image?

Comment: No, Just work in Windows for some time and then log into Ubuntu. When I take this approach I do not see any strange characters appearing in the command prompt inside ubuntu